# PANDAS str.contains Token matching ordering issue

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to match within a column some Company names. 
if my dataframe contains `'book company services ltd'` and the string i want to match is `'book company services'` then this operation works perfectly.

However if my matching string is `'book company ltd'`, in that case it fails to match at all .

Any resolution . Is there a Set wise way to do the same on token levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
df.foo.str.split(' ').apply(lambda l: set(l).issuperset(set('book company ltd'.split(' '))))
```

to check whether each word in `'book company limited'` appears in rows of column `foo` of `df`.

If you want the comparison to be case independent, you can do it with

```
df.foo.str.lower().str.split(' ')... # rest of line from above.
```

Comment: Sorry for using the Thanks comment . I do not have the reputation to upvote. But I have used the said solution and it WORKS as required . If any user finds this comment useful i will be happy :) . Just one more question , is this case independent ?

Comment: @DebayanChakraborty Hey, added an explanation on making it insensitive. Don't worry about the upvote. All the best!

Comment: `df.foo.astype(str).str.split(' ').apply(lambda l: set(map(lambda x:x.lower(),l)).issuperset(set('Book Company Ltd'.lower().split(' '))))` This is what i did to handle cases. if there is a better workaround would be much appreciated also :)

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. My `lower` is at the Pandas level, before the pure-Python stuff. You basically want to push as much as possible to Pandas, as it's more efficient.